# Чи відмінюються іноземні складені імена , та чи взагалі можна їх перекладати?

Tags: переклад, from-english, власні-назви, відмінювання

Сьогодні я зіткнувся з досить цікавим для мене випадком - в одній із нових ігор є персонаж Сьоме березня (March 7 оригінал англійською) . Переглядаючи новий пост в групі що до цієї гри мене збентежив заголовок "Кімната Сьомої Березня" , хоча я не мовник , та *Сьомої Березня * мені здалось неправильним , а саме закінчення -ої
Взагалі так як це є родовий відмінок мені здалось що правильніше буде *Сьомого Березня*, та цей варіант теж мене непокоїть
.Саме тому мене і зацікавило чи можна ,а якщо так то як відмінюються такі імена, та і чи взагалі їх можна перекладати

Answer (score -1):

### СКЛАДНІ І СКЛАДЕНІ ОСОБОВІ ІМЕНА ТА ПРІЗВИЩА

---

## Переклад та відмінювання

Якщо це персонаж жіночої статі, то відмінювання виконано правильно, жін. ст. у род. відмінку: **Сьоме Березня** - **Сьомої Березня**. Та якщо це автоматичний переклад від Google, сталася помилка, виглядає ніби з англійської мови перекладено дату March 7.

### **1. Переклад**

Англійські, іспанські, німецькі та інші імена з мов, що не є близькоспорідненими з українською мовою, зазвичай транслітеруються за практичною транскрипцією, з невеликими особливостями, що перелічені в чинному [**правописі**](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf).

**Прізвища транслітерують завжди**

*Donald Trum* - *Дональд Трамп* (але не *Дональд Козир* або *Дональд Козирний*), *Halle Berry* - *Холлі Беррі* або *Галлі Беррі* чи Геллі Беррі (але не *Холлі Ягода*).

**Імена транслітерують при перекладі офіційних документів, зрідка можливий вжиток відповідників**

*March 7* - *Мач Севен*, *Марта Севен*

**Псевдоніми можна перекладати дослівно або транслітерацією**

*March 7* - *Марта Сім*

**§ 146. Імена та прізвища (прізвиська)**
Імена та прізвища (також прізвиська) людей, що складаються з двох чи трьох компонентів або до складу яких входять прийменники, частки, артиклі тощо, пишемо окремо, разом і з дефісом.

1.2. Окремо пишемо псевдоніми, що побудовані як поєднання імені та прізвища: Джек Лóндон, Жорж Санд, Лéся Україн́́ ка, Мáркó Вовчóк, Панáс Мúрний;

### **2. Відмінювання**

**§ 140. Іменники іншомовного походження звичайно відмінюємо
як відповідні українські іменники:** * Особливості відмінювання власних назв іншомовного походження

п.1 У дво- і полікомпонентних іменах і прізвищах відмінюємо всі складники, за винятком тих, які є невідмінюваними: А́ртура Ко́нана До́йла, Ка́рла Гу́става Емі́ля Маннерге́йма; Хуа́на Ка́рлоса Альфо́нсо Вікто́ра Марі́ї де Бурбо́на.

**§ 142. Відмінювання прізвищ**

Примітка 2. Усі чоловічі прізвища ІІ відміни в родовому відмінку мають закінчення -а (-я) на відміну від деяких співвідносних загальних назв: пор. прізвища *Морóз — Морóз-а*, *Кулíш — Куліш-á*, Коровáй — Коровá-я, Чорнотíнь — Чорнотíн-я, Рись — Рúс-я і загальні назви морóз — морóз-у, кулíш — кулеш-ý, коровáй — коровá-ю, тінь — тíн-і, рись — рúс-і.
Примітка 3. За відповідними відмінами відмінюємо неслов’янські змінювані прізвища: Окуджáва — Окуджáви, Окуджáві й т. д., Шекспíр — Шекспíра, Шекспíрові (Шекспíру) й т. д., Стендáль — Стендáля,

**§ 146. Імена та прізвища (прізвиська)**

п.5. Складені прізвища, псевдоніми або прізвиська з компонентами в називному відмінку відмінюємо в усіх частинах за зразками відмінювання відповідних іменників або прикметників: *Рíчард Лéвове Сéрце — Рíчарда Лéвового Сéрця, Рíчардові (Рíчарду) Лéвовому Сéрцю*.